# Call Macro dynamically when cell value changed by formula

Tags: vba, excel, data-connections

In Excel, through "Data connection", I am getting live data in cell A1. Using A1's value, I am doing some calculation on cell B1. If the value in B1 is TRUE, then that value should be copied to C1.

I have so far been unable to achieve the desired result and would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple =IF formula in C1 suffice ? Like =IF(B1=TRUE,A1,"").

Comment: Not really clear what kind of link it is, but the `Workbook.SetLinkOnData` method might be what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are refreshing cell **A1** externally and want to perform the copy based on cell **B1**'s calculation, then you can use the *Calculate* event macro.

Say we want the first value in **A1** that exceeds 100 to be captured in **C1**.  Once the first value has been captured, no other values above 100 will be copied.

In **B1** we enter:

```
=AND(A1>100,C1="")
```

and then install this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Dim B As Boolean
   B = Range("B1").Value
   If B Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
         Range("C1").Value = Range("A1").Value
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```